# How to use XLPagerTabStrip

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, xlpagertabstrip

I have installed the pod for **XLPagerTabStrip**. Now, what do I have to do to use the feature? Please tell the ordered procedure as it is not understandable for me on other available resources.

Comment: have you figured it out.? i am trying to implement it .

Answer (score 0):

They have full document in their GitHub. Why you don't use that?

Comment: can't understand that